# Is there any way to remove an element by its index value in JQuery [$('.a').index(1).remove();]?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove a set of HTML elements by their index using jQuery.
Is there any way can it be done?

I tried something similar to $('.a').index(1).remove();, but it does not work.

```
/* This is not the actual code, but sample code */
// HTML Part
<ul>
  <li class="a">Milk</li>
  <li class="a">Tea</li>
  <li class="a">Coffee</li>
</ul>

// jQuery Part

$('.a').index(1).remove();

/* If I want to remove Tea from list using its index value */
```

Comment: Also this one [Remove single child at index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437211/remove-single-child-at-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eq()` instead of `index()`

```js
$('.a').eq(0).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="a">Milk</li>
  <li class="a">Tea</li>
  <li class="a">Coffee</li>
</ul>
```